# How to add a hover effect with dynamic styles to a component element?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have this Angular component where hover effect is currently applied with pseudo-class `:hover` in .scss file. But I want to apply the hover effect with dynamic values.

So suppose if I want the element's background to change on hover, the current css looks like this:

```
.element {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;

     &:hover {
          background-color: red;
     }
}
```

But now I want the hover background color to have dynamic values that is available inside the component provided by the user from the UI so the color could be anything. Another thing which I also want to achieve is to add a class to the element when it is selected. What I mean is when hovered, the background will change to a dynamic value but if the element is selected, that same color will be the background color. And if unselected, it will go back to the original color.

I'm new to Angular so I'm not sure how to achieve this. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically set pseudo classes via JavaScript. You would have to either:

1. Implement your own dynamic styling using the mouseover event in your component
2. Swap to a pure CSS solution and let the consumer of your component override the hover pseudo selector with the desired color in their own CSS.

I would favor the second option. Turn off view encapsulation in your component declaration, make sure your component CSS is reasonably contained to just that component via some CSS component methodology like BEM, and just let the consumer override your styles.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I know how to achieve option 1 so no questions about that. But what I understood from option 2 is that it is the same as the current css implementation mentioned in my post. Isn't it? If not, can you please clarify a little bit more?

Comment: Sort of, it just depends on how you want external developers to interact with your component. Turning off view encapsulation has consequences, using a custom mouse over event has mostly cons and few pros. Not turning off view encapsulation and expecting people to override your CSS is inconsistent. I have a personal preference for enabling CSS only solutions, but there isn't a wrong answer. You get to do the fun part of weighing the tradeoffs.

Comment: Upon rereading your question, if the color is dynamically set by the user, you probably should go with the pure JavaScript solution. If I wasn't on my phone, I'd code up an example for you.

Comment: Okay umm I went with ```mouseenter``` and ```mouseleave``` solution and it works perfectly. But now after seeing your comment that it has a lot of cons, I'm kind of confused. I'll just keep it like this for now. If you can, whenever that is, post an example of option 2. That'd be a big help. PS. I'm choosing this as an answer.

Comment: It has cons for extensibility, but if you need to display a color that a user has selected, then a JavaScript solution is the best answer. You can safely ignore everything else I said :P.